# In angularJS, How to refactor an $http call into a Service?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I tried to put the below code into a service but I seem to be missing something! I have to click the button twice to update the list shown in the table:

```
 $scope.todoList = [];
 $scope.showTodoList = function(){

  var url = '/api/v1/todo/list/'+$scope.report.from+'/'+$scope.report.to;

  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.todoList = response.data;
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

So I tried to do this:

```
angular.module('ReportController', []).controller('ReportController', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', '$location', '$localStorage', '$routeParams', 'Report', 'Todo',
  function ($scope, $http, $location, $localStorage, $routeParams, Report, Todo) {

    $scope.todoList = [];

    $scope.showTodoList = function(){
      $scope.todoList = Report.getList($scope.report.from, $scope.report.to);
    }
  }]);
```

then i created a module and added the `factory` there and loaded this module with all others

```
angular.module('ReportService', []).factory('Report', ['$q', '$filter', '$http', '$timeout', function ($q, $filter, $http, $timeout) {

    var list;

    function getList(date_from, date_to){
      var url = '/api/v1/todo/list/'+date_from+'/'+date_to;

      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url
      }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        list = response.data;

      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);

      });
      return list;
    }



    return {
      getList: getList
    };

  }]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you are not waiting for the callback of $http call when returning the list.

You should make the ReportService's getList function to return a callback or a Promise. It will also change a bit how you need to handle the function call in your ReportController.

Example how to do this with callbacks:

ReportService:

```
angular.module('ReportService', []).factory('Report', ['$q', '$filter', '$http', '$timeout', function ($q, $filter, $http, $timeout) {

var list;

function getList(date_from, date_to, callback){
  var url = '/api/v1/todo/list/'+date_from+'/'+date_to;

  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    list = response.data;
    return callback(list);
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
    return callback(null);
  });
}

return {
  getList: getList
};

}]);
```

ReportController:

```
angular.module('ReportController', []).controller('ReportController', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', '$location', '$localStorage', '$routeParams', 'Report', 'Todo',
  function ($scope, $http, $location, $localStorage, $routeParams, Report, Todo) {

    $scope.todoList = [];

    $scope.showTodoList = function(){
      Report.getList($scope.report.from, $scope.report.to, function(res){
        if(res) {
          $scope.todoList = res;
        }
      });
    }
}]);
```